# Sort array of objects in numpy?

Tags: arrays, sorting, object, numpy

How can I efficiently sort an array of objects on two or more attributes in Numpy?

```
class Obj():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

arr = np.array([],dtype=Obj)        

for i in range(10):
    arr = np.append(arr,Obj(i, 10-i))

arr_sort = np.sort(arr, order=a,b) ???
```

Thx, Willem-Jan

Comment: Does numpy support a class for the data type: `np.array([],dtype=Obj)`?

Comment: I'd use a list rather than object array.  List append is faster.  And list sort allows sorting key parameter.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). They don't work directly with Python classes though.

Comment: `dtype=Obj` is treated as `dtype=object`, the generic `object` dtype.  Elements of such an array can be anything, including `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order` parameter only applies to structured arrays:

```
In [383]: arr=np.zeros((10,),dtype='i,i')
In [385]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     arr[i] = (i,10-i)  
In [386]: arr
Out[386]: 
array([(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [387]: np.sort(arr, order=['f0','f1'])
Out[387]: 
array([(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [388]: np.sort(arr, order=['f1','f0'])
Out[388]: 
array([(9, 1), (8, 2), (7, 3), (6, 4), (5, 5), (4, 6), (3, 7), (2, 8),
       (1, 9), (0, 10)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

With a 2d array, `lexsort` provides a similar 'ordered' sort

```
In [402]: arr=np.column_stack((np.arange(10),10-np.arange(10)))
In [403]: np.lexsort((arr[:,1],arr[:,0]))
Out[403]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
In [404]: np.lexsort((arr[:,0],arr[:,1]))
Out[404]: array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int32)
```

With your object array, I could extract the attributes into either of these structures:

```
In [407]: np.array([(a.a, a.b) for a in arr])
Out[407]: 
array([[ 0, 10],
       [ 1,  9],
       [ 2,  8],
      ....
       [ 7,  3],
       [ 8,  2],
       [ 9,  1]])
In [408]: np.array([(a.a, a.b) for a in arr],dtype='i,i')
Out[408]: 
array([(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3),
       (8, 2), (9, 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

The Python `sorted` function will work on `arr` (or its list equivalent)

```
In [421]: arr
Out[421]: 
array([<__main__.Obj object at 0xb0f2d24c>,
       <__main__.Obj object at 0xb0f2dc0c>,
       ....
       <__main__.Obj object at 0xb0f35ecc>], dtype=object)
In [422]: sorted(arr, key=lambda a: (a.b,a.a))
Out[422]: 
[<__main__.Obj at 0xb0f35ecc>,
 <__main__.Obj at 0xb0f3570c>,
 ...
 <__main__.Obj at 0xb0f2dc0c>,
 <__main__.Obj at 0xb0f2d24c>]
```

Your `Obj` class is missing a nice `__str__` method.  I have to use something like `[(i.a, i.b) for i in arr]` to see the values of the `arr` elements.

As I stated in the comment, for this example, a list is much nice than an object array.

```
In [423]: alist=[]
In [424]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     alist.append(Obj(i,10-i))
```

list `append` is faster than the repeated array append.  And object arrays don't add much functionality compared to a list, especially when 1d, and the objects are custom classes like this.  You can't do any math on `arr`, and as you can see, sorting isn't any easier.